# How to Update in Postgresql without affecting the row number?

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa

I have writing API using Spring JPA and Postgresql.

After update statement It's affect the row number of record.

[image: Before Update]

[image: After Update id 2]

The order of record 2 which updated will going to the last order.

I don't want to change the row number

How can I update without changing the row number?

Comment: And please advise us how anyone here can know what each of those columns maps on to in the Entity class if you don't tell us what the class is? while mentioning this perhaps you can tell us WHAT you are updating in the object, and what SQL is invoked by your JPA provider

Comment: Just don't, ever, rely on the implicit order of the rows. If you need rows in a specific order, then add an `order by` clause in your query.

Comment: Found this: http://www.sql-workbench.net/not-sorted/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A database table is an *unordered* set of tuples (also known as a *relation*), so you cannot rely on the order of rows returned from a `SELECT * FROM tablename`.

You need to enforce an ordering with an `ORDER BY` clause if you need it.

The internal reason why the location of a row changes after an update is that PostgreSQL actually writes a new version of the row, which in this case is appended at the end. But you cannot rely on that either: if there is free space in the middle of the table, the new row version can be added there.